# Unable to setup dual boot Fedora with Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, dualboot

I was trying to set up dual boot Fedora 31 with windows 10 on my Asus TUF laptop. But as soon as fedora starts booting up it powers off as it displays some startup logs and then suddenly initiates system shutdown.
I used rufus to create a bootable USB.
I have also disabled secure boot and fast boot.

Also I tried installing ubuntu 18.04 but as soon as I enter my login credentials, it initiates the shutdown process, also when I tried running ubuntu in recovery mode it just works fine. I think there might be a problem with the graphics adapter.

What could be causing this issue?

Update - There might be an issue with Gnome Display Manager, as when I boot Fedora from my thumbdrive it hangs and powers off after the message `[Started] Gnome Display Manager`.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, try an Ubuntu distro without GNOME, e.g., from http://Lubuntu.me or http://Xubuntu.org . Make a LiveUSB with one of those distros and then try booting from the LiveUSB and let us know what happens. If that fails, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it